# hive update lastAccessTime

Tags: hive

I wanted to update  lastAccessTime on hive table ,After google in the web,I get a solution :

```
set hive.exec.pre.hooks = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.UpdateInputAccessTimeHook$PreExec;
```

But If I have two database A & B  the hive sql:

```
 set hive.exec.pre.hooks = 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.UpdateInputAccessTimeHook$PreExec;
    use A;
    insert overwrite A.xxx
    select  c1,c2 from B.xxx;
```

hive returned me

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.InvalidTableException(Table not
>   found B.xxx

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve a table's 'LastAccessTime', run the following commands through the Hive shell, replacing [database_name] and [table_name] with the relevant values.

```
    use [database_name];
    show table extended like '[table_name]';
```

This will return several metrics including the number of milliseconds (rather than the number of seconds) elapsed since Epoch. To format that number as a string representing the timestamp of that moment in the current system's time zone, remove the last three digits from the number and run it through the following command:

```
    select from_unixtime([last_access_time]);
```

Comment: Any idea how this value is updated - doesn't seem to be immediate to me, is there some kind of cache? And what counts as an "access", should any table read cause this to be updated?

Comment: I my case this timestamp seems to be updated, while the LAST_ACCESS_TIME in the Hive metadata store is 0. That does not really make any sense to me, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I happen to want the same effect.
Take sometime and finnaly make it;
your method is right.Just the value mastters;

```
<property>
   <name>hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append</name>
   <value>hive\.exec\.pre\.hooks</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>hive.exec.pre.hooks</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.UpdateInputAccessTimeHook$PreExec</value>
</property>
```

If still not working ,maybe your hive has a bug [HIVE-18060UpdateInputAccessTimeHook fails for non-current database](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18060).
fixed in  CDH5.15 [CDH 5.15.0 Release Notes](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hive-1.1.0-cdh5.15.0.releasenotes.html) if you use cdh .