# How to find updated date for hive tables?

Tags: hive, hiveql

How to find the last DML or DQL update timestamp for Hive table. I can find TransientDDLid by using "formatted describe ". But it is helping in getting Modified Date. How can I figure out the latest UPDATED DATE for a Hive Table(Managed/External)?

Comment: Well, you could check the HDFS files timestamps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149610/hive-update-lastaccesstime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `show table extended like 'table_name';`

It will give number of milliseconds elapsed since epoch.

Copy that number, remove last 3 digits and do `select from_unixtime(no. of milliseconds elapsed since epoch)`

e.g. `select from_unixtime(1532442615733);`

This will give you timestamp of that moment in current system's time zone.

I guess this is what you're looking for...